# How to restore registry to default in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I made a mistake, changed the value of `.exe` in the `registry editor` and currently I can not open the editor again or any other .exe program (nothing) .. Can I back up registry through cmd, I tried with

```
Xcopy c:\windows\system32\config\RegBack c:\windows\system32\config
```

But it returns me "0 files copied", files are in RegBack, OS is Windows 10. Also tried with system restore from 5 different system restore points, but it throws error, any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet you can open the Registry Editor by opening a command prompt (as administrator) and running:

```
regedit
```

---

`.exe` in the classes root are for Explorer to know how to work with `.exe` files.

Command Prompt should therefore be unaffected.

Comment: No I can't open it from .cmd but I can access folders, so tried to copy files. Via bash It returns me `bash: /c/WINDOWS/regedit: Permission denied`. Probably I should change User's permission, somehow ?

Comment: And if I open BASH and type `cmd` then type `regedit` it shows me path to exe with error `No such interface supported` after that show on console `Access denied`

Comment: Do not use Linux on sensitive Windows files!

Comment: Can you use the REG command in a command prompt? It is basically regedit but in a CMD interface. You can also try renaming regedit.exe to regedit.com and see if you can start it from the commandline then.

Comment: Also, you do need to run cmd as Administrator.

Comment: Where did Bash come from?!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: My psychic powers tell me OP is using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did:

1. Enable Administrator account, base on [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2014/11/12/how-to-enable-the-hidden-windows-10-administrator-account/) article:

   > 1. Activate the Start menu on the system.
   > 2. Type lusrmgr.msc and select the result that is returned to you.
   > 3. Left-click on "Users" in the left sidebar. You get a list of all accounts of the local system on the right.
   > 4. Right-click on Administrator and select Properties from the context menu.
   > 5. Remove the checkmark from "Account is disabled" on the Administrator Properties window and click apply, then ok.
2. Open the Administrator account from **Start -> Change user**
3. Open `Git Bash here` from some folder with right click, then open `cmd` from BASH and type `regedit`.
4. Back values from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> exefile` and `exefile -> shell -> open -> command` to default (which I changed early).

*P.S: I found a good way to change the values of registry if you are already closed Registry editor, this is example for exefile:*

1. Double-click a text (.txt) file in your system. (This opens Notepad.)
2. From the File menu, click New.
3. Copy the following contents and paste into Notepad.

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe] @="exefile"
   ```
4. Save the file with .REG extension.
5. Double-click the file to run it.
6. This fixes the .exe file type ProgID.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for your help you guided me to open cmd from Administrator user : )

Comment: You're welcome. If you really want to be awesome, hit the checkmark near my answer, given that that is basically what got you to the solution eventually. :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution might be 
to go back to a previous system restore point.

See the article (among many)
[How to recover using System Restore on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-system-restore-windows-10#recover_restore_point_windows10).

One small problem : This is handled by a the process `SystemPropertiesProtection.exe`, which is an `.exe` file! Ouch!

You will therefore need to do this from a boot USB, as follows:

- On a working PC, go to the
  [Microsoft software download website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
- Download the Windows 10 media creation tool and then run it
- Select *Create installation media for another PC*
- Choose a language, edition, and architecture (64-bit or 32-bit)
- Follow the steps to create installation media, and then select *Finish*
- Connect the installation media you created to your nonfunctional PC, and then turn it on.
- On the initial setup screen, enter your language and other preferences, and then select *Next*. If you don't see the setup screen, your PC might not be set up in the BIOS to boot from the drive.
- Select *Repair your computer*
- On the *Choose an option* screen, select *Troubleshoot*
- Select *Advanced options > System Restore*.

You might also be able to boot into the Command Prompt,
with a good chance that the copy will work in that environment.
Only that this might take you back too far in time.

Comment: Read the question, man : )) I already tried with system restore, there is 5 different system restore points, but cannot restore, has a file who cannot be restored

Answer (score 0):

registry associations are not recursive.

1) Turn on "show file extensions

2) Create a new text file on the deskotp

3) type 3 letters `cmd` into it and save

4) rename to .bat

5) right click -> run as administrator

6) `regedit`

7) Undo your change

Comment: The OP seems to be able to run `cmd`; why do you believe that this is helpful?

Comment: @G-Man: There's a couple other ways to get a `cmd` open that bypass file associations, but none that get an administrative `cmd` open that I know of without creating some files. My understanding of borking `.exe` association is admin elevate of executables is completely broken, but this invokes elevation on a `.bat`.